# how to display specific data from database to listview in sqlitedatabase

Tags: android, listview, sqlite

i want to display specific data from my database where all project under the clients company will display.. how to display data from the result of the query.. what if multiple projects under the company found is the listview can list it all? im new to android ..thanks in advance

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_client_module);

    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

    btnrefresh = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btncrefresh);
    btnrefresh.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Cursor cursor = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase().rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + User.TABLE, null);
            if(cursor.moveToFirst())
            {
                String comnameproj = cursor.getString(5);
                Cursor qcursor = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase().rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + Project.TABLE, null);

                if(qcursor.getString(8).equals(comnameproj)) {

                    ProjectCrud pcrud = new ProjectCrud(ClientModule.this);

                    ArrayList<HashMap<String , String >> projectList = pcrud.getProjectList();
                    if (projectList.size()!=0){
                        //entrylist = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
                        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {
                                project_Id = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.project_Id);
                                String projectId = project_Id.getText().toString();
                                Intent objintent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ProjectDetail.class);
                                objintent.putExtra("project_Id", Integer.parseInt( projectId ));
                                startActivity(objintent);
                            }
                        });

                        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(ClientModule.this,projectList, R.layout.project_entry, new String []{"id", "title"}, new int[]{R.id.project_Id, R.id.project_title});
                        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
                    }else {
                        Toast.makeText(ClientModule.this, "No Project!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }




                }
            }

        }
    });
```

this the my table

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 4;



private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "mobileorg.db";

public DBHelper(Context context){
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db){

    String CREATE_TABLE_PROJECT = "CREATE TABLE " + Project.TABLE + "("
            + Project.KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
            + Project.KEY_title + " TEXT,"
            + Project.KEY_type + " TEXT,"
         //   + Project.KEY_priority + " INTEGER,"
            + Project.KEY_timeframe + " TEXT,"
            + Project.KEY_start + " TEXT,"
            + Project.KEY_end + " TEXT,"
            + Project.KEY_cost + " INTEGER,"
            + Project.KEY_status + " TEXT,"
            + Project.KEY_companyproj + " TEXT" + ");";

    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_PROJECT);

    String CREATE_TABLE_USER = "CREATE TABLE " + User.TABLE + "("
            + User.KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
            + User.KEY_priv +" TEXT,"
            + User.KEY_username + " TEXT,"
            + User.KEY_usertype + " TEXT,"
            + User.KEY_sex + " TEXT,"
            + User.KEY_usercompany + " TEXT,"
            + User.KEY_usermail + " TEXT,"
            + User.KEY_usercontact + " INTEGER,"
            + User.KEY_useradd + " TEXT,"
            + User.KEY_loguser + " TEXT,"
            + User.KEY_logpass + " TEXT,"
            + User.KEY_logconfirm + " TEXT" + ");";

    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_USER);

    String CREATE_TABLE_COMPANY = "CREATE TABLE " + Company.TABLE + "("
            + Company.KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
            + Company.KEY_cname + " TEXT,"
            + Company.KEY_cstanding + " TEXT,"
            + Company.KEY_crepres + " TEXT,"
            + Company.KEY_ccontact + " TEXT,"
            + Company.KEY_cemail + " TEXT" + ");";

    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_COMPANY);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion){

    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXIST" + Project.TABLE);
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXIST" + User.TABLE);
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXIST" + Company.TABLE);


    onCreate(db);
}

public static boolean validateUser(String loguser, String logpass){

    return false;

}


}
```

this my updated  query version .. but nothing happen .. nothing displays to my listview..

```
public class ClientModule extends ActionBarActivity {

private DBHelper dbHelper;

Button btnrefresh;
ListView lv ;
TextView project_Id;
String comnameproj;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_client_module);

    dbHelper = new DBHelper(ClientModule.this);

    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

    btnrefresh = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btncrefresh);
    btnrefresh.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Cursor cursor = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase().rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + User.TABLE, null);
            if(cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    comnameproj = cursor.getString(5);
                } while (cursor.moveToNext());

            }

                Cursor qcursor = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase().rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + Project.TABLE, null);
                if (qcursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {

                    if (qcursor.getString(8).equals(comnameproj)) {

                        ProjectCrud pcrud = new ProjectCrud(ClientModule.this);

                        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> projectList = pcrud.getProjectList();
                        if (projectList.size() != 0) {
                            //entrylist = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
                            lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                                    project_Id = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.project_Id);
                                    String projectId = project_Id.getText().toString();
                                    Intent objintent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ProjectDetail.class);
                                    objintent.putExtra("project_Id", Integer.parseInt(projectId));
                                    startActivity(objintent);
                                }
                            });

                            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(ClientModule.this, projectList, R.layout.refresh_project, new String[]{"id", "title"}, new int[]{R.id.project_Id, R.id.project_title});
                            lv.setAdapter(adapter);
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(ClientModule.this, "No Project!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }

                    }


                }while (cursor.moveToNext()) ;

                }

        }
    });



}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_client_module, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.exit_client) {

        finish();
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
 }
```

Comment: You are running database queries on the main thread. Be very careful, this could stutter the UI!

Comment: oh.. thanks .. what am i going to do?

Comment: @Jeraline Does your current query return any result?

Comment: yes it does .. from the table user..

Comment: @Jeraline you could start by reading the android training guide, especially the one on background job: https://developer.android.com/training/best-background.html

Comment: @Jeraline Please post your create table statements. I would like to see the structure of your database tables.

Comment: @Jeraline Do you want to select the projects of all companies or the projects of just one company?

Comment: i want to select all projects under clients company

Comment: @Jeraline Who specifies the clients company?

Comment: the user.. on user table i have usercompany field to be compare with the project table .. on project table i have companyproj field

Comment: @Jeraline I don't see where you are populating the listview with what you retrieved from the database. Or are you?

Comment: well honestly thats my problem i dont know how to populate my listview.. i dont know where to put the result of my query

Comment: Okay, if I understand your problem correctly, you want to select all the projects in your projects table that are for a particular user in your users table. Am I right?

Comment: yeah .. yes thats right

Comment: What determines which user's projects gets selected from the database table?

Comment: companyproj from the project table

Comment: No, that's not what I mean. Do you specify which user's projects get selected from the projects table or do you just pick the projects of the first user in the users table?

Comment: i just pick it.. sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to modify your SQLite SELECT query. Since you want to select the list of projects owned by a particular user, you should write your query as shown below (I assume that you specify the user's project name in a `String` called `userCompany`):

```
btnrefresh.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + Project.TABLE + " WHERE " + Project.KEY_companyproj " = " + userCompany;

        Cursor qCursor = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase().rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> projectList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        /* loop through all rows and add to list */
        if (qCursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                HashMap<String, String> project = new HashMap<String, String>();
                project.put("id", cursor.getString(String.valueOf(cursor.getColumnIndex(Project.KEY_ID))));
                project.put("title", cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Project.KEY_title)));
                projectList.add(project);
            } while (qCursor.moveToNext());
        }

        qCursor.close();

        // populate the listview with projectlist here 
    }
};
```

Let me know if this helps.